# GridView Click not working in android

Tags: android, gridview, click

hello i have a probleme with gridview click

this is my xml row code and i set all textview and imageview and chexbox to android:clickable="false" but when i click in item not action is working

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/laybackground"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cadreaccesshadow"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageuser"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
         android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cadretransp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
         android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
             android:clickable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userjob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
             android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usercompany"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
             android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/usermail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#cfcfcf"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my code

```
  gridView = (GridView) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            System.out.println("kkkkkkkkk");

                            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)arg1.findViewById(R.id.usermail);
                             checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());    
                             gridArray.get(arg2).setetat(checkBox.isChecked());
                             customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }

                    });
```

my problem is when i click the item hi dont't working

someone can help me please

Comment: can you post your customadapter class...,and try to use log in your appluication..and see,its clicking or not

Comment: try my answer it will work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your LinearLayout

For eg.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/laybackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cadreaccesshadow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```